# MVC sending variable HTML from form to database

Tags: html, forms, model-view-controller

so i have the next problem, i want to send variable from view to database, i succeded but i cant sent from select..I can send surname firstname and skill but when i send teams it cames null..

```
<form id="addPlayerForm" action="#">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="txtSurname" name="player_surname">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="txtFirstname" name="player_firstname">
    <br />
   SKILL:
    <br>
    <input type="number" id="txtSkill" name="player_skill" />
    <br />
    <br>
    <select>
        <option selected="selected" value="0">no</option>
        @foreach(var teamInfo in Model.Teams)
        {
            <option value="@teamInfo.Key" name="id_team">@teamInfo.Value</option>
        }
    </select>
    <br>
    <p>
        <input id="addPlayerButton" type="button" value="Save" />
    </p>
</form>
```

here i parse from my model to my database model..

```
  public players MapPlayerFromForm(PlayerModel formPlayer)
       {
            var toRet = new players
                {
                 player_firstname=formPlayer.player_firstname,
                  player_surname=formPlayer.player_surname,
                 player_skill=formPlayer.player_skill,
                id_team=formPlayer.teams.id_team

        };
        return toRet;

    }
```

Comment: i just solved this thing

Comment: glad you found a solution! Maybe you could post it as an answer to your own question, so that users stumbling into this issue in the future will find a track of the steps you took to solve it !

Comment: so i just had to add name at this select `<select name="id_team">` and declare an id_team in my class, not to use the id_team from table teams